# Flex wrap layout and parent width

Tags: css, flexbox

Either I'm missing something or this is just how flex works.

Given a wrapping flex container with a max-width as children wrap the parents width remains at the max-width even though by wrapping the children the width could be reduced.

This makes it impossible to align the container to the center of it's container.

Here's a codepen illustrating the issue:

https://codepen.io/rsouthgate/pen/PozPyXZ

```
    .container {
      display: inline-flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      max-width: 300px;
    }
```

[image: This space is now unused]

So how can I get the container to not take up the space on the right after the wrap?

Comment: *Either I'm missing something or this is just how flex works.* --> it's the second one unfortunately

Answer (score -1):

Here are some of the possibilities via `justify-content`, in order: `center`, `space-around`, `space-between`. These all just change how the excess looks. If you want to make the children themselves take up the remaining space, use `flex-grow: 1` instead.

You can read up more on css tricks: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

```css
.outer {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.container {
  justify-content: center;
  background: grey;
  display: inline-flex;
  margin: 0 auto 10px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 300px;
}

.child {
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background: white;
  margin: 5px;
}

.container2 {
  justify-content: space-around;
  background: grey;
  display: inline-flex;
  margin: 0 auto 10px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 300px;
}

.container3 {
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: grey;
  display: inline-flex;
  margin: 0 auto 10px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  max-width: 300px;
}

.container4 {
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: grey;
  display: inline-flex;
  margin: 0 auto 10px;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  width: 300px;
}

.child-grow {
  flex-basis: 25px;
  flex-grow: 1;
  height: 25px;
  background: white;
  margin: 5px;
}
```

```html
center
<div class="outer">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
</div>
Space around
<div class="outer">
  <div class="container2">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="container2">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
</div>

Space between
<div class="outer">
  <div class="container3">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="container3">
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
    <div class="child"></div>
  </div>
</div>

Flex grow
<div class="outer">
  <div class="container4">
    <div class="child-grow"></div>
    <div class="child-grow"></div>
    <div class="child-grow"></div>
    <div class="child-grow"></div>
    <div class="child-grow"></div>
    <div class="child-grow"></div>
    <div class="child-grow"></div>
    <div class="child-grow"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="container4">
    <div class="child-grow"></div>
    <div class="child-grow"></div>
    <div class="child-grow"></div>
    <div class="child-grow"></div>
    <div class="child-grow"></div>
    <div class="child-grow"></div>
    <div class="child-grow"></div>
    <div class="child-grow"></div>
    <div class="child-grow"></div>
    <div class="child-grow"></div>
    <div class="child-grow"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```